# Slow initial load of URL

Tags: cefsharp

We are using CefSharp 73. When loading URL for the first time, after the browser is created, it takes from 2-8 sec depending on the machine hardware. Performance profiling shows that this delay is not coming from page resource loading. We suspect that this is because of starting of the browser subprocess. Are there options that can be turned on/off that can improve the starting time of the browser subprocess or somehow to have browser subprocess prepared/started before the page load so we can avoid those delays?

Can I expect improvements in subprocess start time if I upgrade to latest version of CefSharp version using new Chromium Network API?

Could there be another reason other than subprocess startup that can slow down first URL load?

Comment: You can test out the latest version using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: If you don't need a proxy then you can disable proxy resolution to improve startup performance https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L75

Comment: We already have proxy resolution disabled.

Comment: In future please include that sort of detail.